# Adding functions to Ripple emulator for plugins failing at cordova.exec

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ripple

We are developing a mobile app with Cordova with a number of plugins and checks in Chrome through Ripple emulator. Apparently some plugins use native functions not implemented by Ripple, which breaks part of the app functionality in Chrome.

**The question:** how to add emulator functions to Ripple? Below appears what I've found so far and what is missing from making it to work.

In console an error like the following can be seen:

```
missing exec:Keyboard.close
ripple.js:40 TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at ripple.define.module.exports.exec (http://localhost:4428/ripple/assets/ripple.js:40:28665)
    at Function.Keyboard.close (http://localhost:4428/plugins/com.ionic.keyboard/www/keyboard.js:14:2)
    ...
```

In `keyboard.js`:

```
exec = require('cordova/exec');
// Line 14, where from the exception stacktrace
exec(null, null, "Keyboard", "close", []);
```

From some googling, it's clear that `cordova.exec` is a connector between the Javascript part and the native backend. I assumed, Ripple should replace this and indeed there's a [bridge.js](https://github.com/apache/incubator-ripple/blob/master/lib/client/platform/cordova/2.0.0/bridge.js) presumably doing exactly that. And it even has function `add()`, apparently for user supplied emulators. So I grokked, that in my code I should write something like:

```
var bridge = ripple('platform/cordova/2.0.0/bridge'); 
bridge.add( 
    "Keyboard", 
    { close: function () {} } 
);
```

Alas, `ripple` is undefined at the app scope. And this is the **missing part** - how to get access to `ripple`?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem and all that I could think - to change the `www` part of the plugin like this:

```
var exec    = require('cordova/exec');

// --> here is the start of my code

if (exec.toString().indexOf("emulator") > 0) {
    exec = emulation;
}

function emulation(success, fail, service, action, args) {
    if (action === "add") {
        var options = args[0];
        alert("Local Notification added: " + options.message);
    }
}

// --> the end of my code
```

What can you tell about this?

May be someone say how to avoid this trick. ))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what we do now. There are a number of problems: any update/change to a plugin will remove this,  we prefer not to save plugins in source control, so again, this change isn't saved, and so on... I'll try to understand how exactly @cordova@ and @ripple@ are related.

Comment: As far as I understood Cordova nothing knows about Ripple, but Ripple simple knows about the main Cordova plugings and how to emulate them. My quick analizing of the ripple.js didn't help me how could I extend the Ripple emulator. ((( Could you inform me if you solve this problem?

Comment: I would also like to get in on this solution. Would be nice to test more with ripple and chrome and less with emulators.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my complete solution: http://www.badpenguin.org/ionic-keyboard-ripple-emulator

Uses **window.parent.ripple** instead.

Also *close()* its not enough; you need to mock *init()* and other functions.